# Generic views for updating objects?

Tags: python, django, generics, django-views

How do I rewrite the function-based view that only updates an object into a class-based view? Something like this (wrote this for a tutorial).

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required
@permission_required("catalog.mark_returned")
def mark_returned(request, pk):
    bk = BookInstance.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if bk.status == "a":
        #some tests here
    bk.status = "a"
    bk.due_back = None
    bk.borrower = None
    bk.save()
    return redirect("on-loan")
```

And in general, does it make sense to use generics for things like that? 
Because currently, I only use the generic list and detail views.
Sorry for beginner-level questions:)

Answer (score 0):

It's a view without a template or a form; that kinda excludes the usefulness of just about every generic view except the basic View class itself.
You would override the **C**lass**B**ased**V**iew's dispatch method (since the request method does not matter) with the logic of your function view. 
The pk value can be accessed through `self.args[0]` or `self.kwargs['_name_of_captured_variable_here']`.

Does it make sense? In general, I would say becoming familiar with CBVs and especially the generic ones will do you good in the long run. In your special case, however, you gain or lose nothing by using a CBV over function view. The view is just too simplistic.